# Creating store procedure at teradata

Tags: stored-procedures, teradata

there is error at sql while creating stored procedure at teradata 16 , please what is the wrong with this query?

REPLACE PROCEDURE tutorial_db.banks(out test Varchar(20))
BEGIN
   select name from tutorial_db.banks
END;

Answer (score 0):

Teradata's SPs are based on Standard SQL, to return a result set you must define a cursor

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE tutorial_db.banks(OUT test VARCHAR(20)) 
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1 -- add 1 for each result set to be returned
BEGIN  
   -- dummy cursor declaration
   DECLARE cur2 CURSOR WITH RETURN ONLY FOR      
   SELECT NAME FROM tutorial_db.banks;

   -- don't close within the SP
   OPEN cur2;
END;
```

Cursors are usually bad but this WITH RETURN ONLY cursor is not processed row by row within the SP, it's just an answer set.

Comment: Thanks @dnoeth for reply .. i did this and procedure created but error appear  Named list is not supported for arguments of a procedure.?

Comment: You must call it using a parameter name for the OUT variable, e.g. `call tutorial_db.banks(test)`